# How can I add time to the original time at PHP

Tags: php, date

I have an array containing:

```
$_ENTER = array('TIME_START' => date('H:i A'),'TIME_END' => /*here I want to put time but added by munutes or hours*/ );

echo $_ENTER['TIME_START'];
echo $_ENTER['TIME_END'];
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strtotime` and some English:

```
$_ENTER = array('TIME_START' => date('H:i A'),
                'TIME_END'   => date('H:i A', strtotime('+1 minute')));

$_ENTER = array('TIME_START' => date('H:i A'),
                'TIME_END'   => date('H:i A', strtotime('+1 hour')));
```